# if element width is greater than, then execute jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, width, element, dynamic-css

I have the following javascript right below the relevant html area and it is not seem to be working. I'm pretty sure I have the correct method of getting the width of the relevant div tag but not sure why the

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var pageWidthNow = document.getElementById('top-area').clientWidth;

if (pageWidthNow > 700) {
    $('#search-form').addClass(topRightSearchBox);
};
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try `console.log(pageWidthNow)` ?

Comment: is topRightSearchBox a variable?

Comment: topRightSearchBox is a class that I pre-assigned a few css variables to

Comment: i meant within the js, but that answered my question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it looks like you just need to add quotes

```
$('#search-form').addClass("topRightSearchBox");
```